# VS Code Remote Development: Container postCreateCommand doesn't run

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm trying to configure SSH authentication for a remote development workspace, as detailed in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container):

```
{
  "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
  "runArgs": [
    // ...
    "-v",
    "${env:HOME}${env:USERPROFILE}/.ssh:/root/.ssh-localhost:ro"
  ],
  "postCreateCommand": "echo \"copying ssh keys...\" && mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cp -r ~/.ssh-localhost/* ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*",
  extensions: [
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Note that I've added an `echo` statement at the beginning of that line, just to make sure I'd know if it runs. Other than that, it's identical to the documentation.

However, it seems that the `postCreateCommand` is never run. If I look at the Dev Containers terminal output I see neither the expected `docker exec` command nor the `copying ssh keys...` output from my `echo` statement, and `ls -a /root`from inside the container shows the `.ssh-localhost` folder, but not `.ssh`.

I see no error messages in the logs either. I've tried triggering "Remote Development: Rebuild Container" as well as deleting both container and image before reloading the window, but get the same result anyway.

What configuration am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, so I can't be 100% sure this is what was my issue, but at the same time I was working on getting this configuration up and running, I also tried to optimize start time by mounting a named volume at `~/.vscode-server`.

This turned out to be a "bad" idea for this specific use case, since whether the `postCreateCommand` should run or not is determined by the existence of a marker file present inside that directory (and a level or two down the file tree). Thus, when I re-built the container and restarted the VS Code window, the volume was re-mounted to the new container and the marker file was already present, so the command was not run.

A better solution to this problem, I have found, is to add the following to your Dockerfile instead of having a `postCreateCommand`:

```
RUN echo "\n\nif [ -d ~/.bashrc.d ]; then\n  for rc in ~/.bashrc.d/*rc; do\n    . \$rc\n  done\nfi\n" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

where `$HOME` is either `/root` or `/home/$USER` depending on whether you're running the container as root or not.

This, then, lets you volume-mount a directory to the `~/.bashrc.d` location, and each file matching `*rc` in that directory will be run as part of the profile script. The SSH setup script above can be put in an `sshrc` file there, instead, surrounded by `if [[ -d ~/.ssh ]]` to avoid running it every time.